# Specifying "any instance of class Foo" for mock assert_called_once_with()?

Tags: python, mocking

In `assert_called_once_with`, how can I specify a parameter is "any instance of class Foo"?

For example:

```
class Foo(): pass
def f(x): pass
def g(): f(Foo())
import __main__
from unittest import mock
```

`mock.ANY` of course passes:

```
with mock.patch.object(__main__, 'f') as mock_f:
  g()
  mock_f.assert_called_once_with(mock.ANY)
```

and of course, another instance of Foo doesn't pass.

```
with mock.patch.object(__main__, 'f') as mock_f:
  g()
  mock_f.assert_called_once_with(Foo())

AssertionError: Expected call: f(<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fd38411d0b8>)
                  Actual call: f(<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fd384111f98>)
```

What can I put as my expected parameter such that any instance of Foo will make the assertion pass?

Comment: Why not `assert_called_once()` then `assertIsInstance` the received value?

Comment: I think this is what I will do.  Glad you added it to your answer, both solutions are informative.

Comment: I quite like `mock_f.assert_called_once_with(AnyInstanceOf(Foo))`, but YMMV!

Comment: I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple solution is to do this in two steps:

```
with mock.patch.object(__main__, 'f') as mock_f:
    g()
    mock_f.assert_called_once()
    self.assertIsInstance(mock_f.mock_calls[0].args[0], Foo)
```

---

However, if you look at [the implementation of `ANY`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3e5330130810e485f1abbf192590b7109880a4da/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2347-L2359):

```
class _ANY(object):
    "A helper object that compares equal to everything."

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ANY>'

ANY = _ANY()
```

you can see it's just an object that's equal to anything. So you could define your own equivalent that's equal to any instance of `Foo`:

```
class AnyFoo:
    "A helper object that compares equal to every instance of Foo."

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Foo)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not isinstance(other, Foo)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ANY Foo>'


ANY_FOO = AnyFoo()
```

Or more generically:

```
class AnyInstanceOf:
    "A helper object that compares equal to every instance of the specified class."

    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.cls = cls

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.cls)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not isinstance(other, self.cls)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<ANY {self.cls.__name__}>"


ANY_FOO = AnyInstanceOf(Foo)
```

Either way, you can use it as you would `ANY`:

```
with mock.patch.object(__main__, 'f') as mock_f:
    g()
    mock_f.assert_called_once_with(ANY_FOO)
```