# Reference a nested function in unittest assert_called_with()

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

How can I reference nested functions in `MagicMock.<method>.assert_called_with()`?

I want to mock an object (called here `EventObject`) that can distribute events to installed event handlers.

The signature for handler installation looks like this:

```
class EventObject:
    def install_handler(handler_func):
        pass
```

A function that installs as event handler a nested function:

```
def setup_handler(event_obj):
    def handle_event():
        pass

    event_obj.install_handler(handle_event)
```

Now how to test this? I tried:

```
def test_listen():
    event_obj = MagicMock(spec=EventObject)
    setup_handler(event_obj)
    event_obj.install_handler.assert_called_with(setup_handler.handle_event)
```

But this gives `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'handle_event'`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can't* access `handle_event` - it's not an attribute of `setup_handler`, it's just a local variable and therefore inaccessible outside that scope. All you can say outside `setup_handler` is that the `install_handler` attribute got called with *something*, e.g. using [`ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any):

```py
def test_listen():
    event_obj = MagicMock(spec=EventObject)
    setup_handler(event_obj)
    event_obj.install_handler.assert_called_with(ANY)
```

*(See my answer to [Specifying "any instance of class Foo" for mock assert_called_once_with()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64973215/3001761) for more specific assertions - you could do e.g. `AnyInstanceOf(Callable)` instead.)*

However, given that the function's being passed to `install_handler`, which is now mocked out, you can then test that this function does the right thing by accessing it on the `mock_calls` and interacting with it:

```py
def test_listen():
    event_obj = MagicMock(spec=EventObject)
    setup_handler(event_obj)
    handler = event_obj.install_handler.mock_calls[0].args[0]
    # exercise handler
```