# mock assert_called_with treat argument as unordered list

Tags: python, django, mocking, python-unittest.mock

I have some mocked function and I try to test that the arguments I pass there are correct.
One of the arguments is a list generated based on DB queryset, lets say `[{"id": 1}, {"id": 13}]`
The function doesn't care about the order of dicts in a list, so it works the same with a reversed (shuffled) list.

I also have a test to check arguments are passed correctly:

```py
function_mock.assert_called_once_with(
    argument1='some_string',
    argument2='another_string',
    argument3={'some_dict_key': False},
    ...
    my_list=[{"id": 1}, {"id": 13}],
)
```

The problem is that on different environments queryset produces records in different order, resulting in `[{"id": 1}, {"id": 13}]` on some environments and `[{"id": 13}, {"id": 1}]`(different order) on other. This results in tests pass on some environments and fail on other.

Is there a way to inform mock that this argument should be treated as an unordered list?
Something similar to `my_list=mock.any_order([{...}, {...}])`

---

P.S. I know about `call_args_list` so I can check arguments one by one, and apply `set` when necessary, but I'd like to avoid this solution unless there is better one.

Comment: The values are just compared by equality, so you can write a custom matcher (see an example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64973325/3001761) and do e.g. `my_list=AnyOrder([...])`

Comment: this seems like a common enough scenario to not have some built-in matchers for, or even just an optional parameter in assertListEqual()